# Multithread operations in WCF Service contract implementation

Tags: multithreading, wcf, c#-4.0

I've seen a project lately using a background worker to make some operations (*get data from other web services*) and throw the data using events to the client. This project is a WCF service and consume by an ASP.NET web site by another class library as WCF client role and throwing in turn events to the application. This all multithreaded series made me curious to examine. I've seen that this is a `basicHttpBinding` binding and the only behavior to the service is the `UseSynchronizationContext=false` where I found out that they added it after unexplained exception which is normal :)

Now I'm asking about the default `ConcurrencyMode` for the `basicHttpBinding`. Shouldn't they make it `Reentrant` or this is the default behavior?

Is this scenario will continue failing cause they already have an unexplained reference not set to an instance of an object if the WCF service is down from the client?
I believe using multithread operations in a WCF service consume by ASP.NET project which relies on IIS handling is bad cause the page could be sent to the client before the WCF service return data to the client class library and append these to the page.
Can you discuss the above and explain your thoughts?

Shouldn't be better when you need such an asynchronous programming style to inform WCF comsumers to notify after long operation using `CallbackContracts` and embedded WCF technologies, rather multithreading operations?

Need clarification to correct the design and have some proves that this is a bad service architecture, if it is for real, which I suspect!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not inherently bad architecture, but it sounds like it does create a number of possible pitfalls.

The WCF client library is leaving all the coordination up to the ASP.NET application. If the ASP.NET app isn't checking that a call to the WCF service has been completed, then it risks using variables before they have been set with values from the service, and other such race conditions unless explicitly setting up some manner of coordinating the initial call against the completion events.

My recommendation would be to rewrite the WCF client asynchronous methods to return `Task` objects, from the `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace ([MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235678.aspx)). In this way you can spin off the background processing calling the WCF service, and use the `Result` property of the `Task` to ensure the service has completed.

An example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task<string> t = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        return MyWcfClientClass.StaticAsyncMethod(MyArguments);
    }

    /* other control initialization stuff here, while the task 
       and WCF call continue processing in background */

    /* Calling Result causes the thread to wait for the task to 
       complete as necessary, to ensure we have our correct value */
    MyLabel1.Text = t.Result;
}
```

Comment: Nice one, thanx, will try and do what you recommend! thanx